# Rad Gird Nested Child Template Grid Don't Show

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I want to bind radgid in Asp:place holder and it work perfectly but I want expand that bind radgrid that don’t expant just spin ajaxmanager.

Home.ascx

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgItemHistory" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPreRender="rgItemHistory_PreRender" OnItemCommand="rgItemHistory_ItemCommand"  OnNeedDataSource="rgItemHistory_NeedDataSource" >
                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ItemID,HistoryDate" ExpandCollapseColumn-HeaderStyle-Width="1px">
                    <Columns>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="ItemID" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" UniqueName="ItemID" Visible="false" />

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="HistoryDate" HeaderText="HistoryDate" UniqueName="HistoryDate" >
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost" UniqueName="Cost" >
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MfgrPartListSale" HeaderText="MfgrPartListSale" UniqueName="MfgrPartListSale" >
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MfgrPartWSale" HeaderText="MfgrPartWSale" UniqueName="MfgrPartWSale" >
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="60%" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="60%" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 

                    </Columns>

                    <NestedViewTemplate >
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="pnlBOMHistory">
                            <%--<uctrl:BOMHistory id="ucBOMHistory" runat="server" ></uctrl:BOMHistory>--%>
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </NestedViewTemplate>

                </MasterTableView>
                <ClientSettings>
                </ClientSettings>

            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Home.ascx.cs

```
 protected void rgItemHistory_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ItemID"]) >= 0)
            {
                Item objItem = new Item();
                objItem.ItemId = Id;
                rgItemHistory.DataSource = objItem.GetItemHistory();
                objItem = null;
            }

        }

protected void rgItemHistory_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (GridDataItem item in rgItemHistory.MasterTableView.Items)
            {

                if (item.Expanded)
                {

                    string userControlName = "~/BOMHistory.ascx";
                    Control userControl = Page.LoadControl(userControlName);
                    PlaceHolder panel = (PlaceHolder)item.ChildItem.FindControl("pnlBOMHistory");
                    //Panel panel = (Panel)item.ChildItem.FindControl("pnlBOMHistory");

                    UCtrlBOMHistory uc = userControl as UCtrlBOMHistory;

                    uc.Id = Convert.ToInt32(item.GetDataKeyValue("ItemID"));
                    uc.HistoryDate = item.GetDataKeyValue("HistoryDate").ToString();
                    uc.Type = Type;//"FinishGood";


                    panel.Controls.Add(userControl);

                }



            }



        }
```

Home1.axcs

```
<tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>

            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMain" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Home1.ascx.cs

```
public void DefineStructure()
        {

            RadGrid grd = new RadGrid();
            grd.ID = "rgrdMain";
            grd.MasterTableView.Columns.Clear();
            grd.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Clear();
            grd.EnableLinqExpressions = false;
            grd.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced;
            //grd.PageSize = 20;
            grd.PageSize = 999;

            //grd.ClientSettings.Scrolling.AllowScroll = true;
            //grd.ClientSettings.Scrolling.UseStaticHeaders = true;
            //grd.ClientSettings.Scrolling.SaveScrollPosition = true;
            //grd.ClientSettings.Scrolling.ScrollHeight = 500;
            //grd.ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnGridCreated = "GridCreated";

            // Added by Herin 
            grd.ShowFooter = true;
            grd.FooterStyle.CssClass = "footerBackColor";


            if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("BillOfMaterialListing.aspx"))
            {
                grd.MasterTableView.CommandItemDisplay = GridCommandItemDisplay.None;
                //grd.MasterTableView.CommandItemTemplate = new BOMCommandItemTemplate();
            }
            else
            {
                grd.MasterTableView.CommandItemDisplay = GridCommandItemDisplay.Bottom;
                grd.MasterTableView.CommandItemTemplate = new BOMHistoryCommandItemTemplate();
            }

            grd.ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnHierarchyExpanded = "function() {if(window.parent){if(window.parent.resizeIFrame){window.parent.resizeIFrame();}}}";
            grd.ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnHierarchyCollapsed = "function() {if(window.parent){if(window.parent.resizeIFrame){window.parent.resizeIFrame();}}}";
            grd.ClientSettings.Selecting.AllowRowSelect = true;


            //FinishedGood/SubAssembly/Component/PurchasedItem/Asset Master
            //if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "FinishedGood" || Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "SubAssembly" || Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "Component" || Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "PurchasedItem" || Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "Asset")
            if (Type == "FinishedGood" || Type == "SubAssembly" || Type == "Component" || Type == "PurchasedItem" || Type == "Asset")
            {
                grd.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(rgrdItem_NeedDataSource);
                grd.ItemDataBound += new GridItemEventHandler(rgrdItem_ItemDataBound);
                grd.ItemCommand += new GridCommandEventHandler(rgrdItem_ItemCommand);
                grd.PreRender += new EventHandler(rgrdItem_PreRender)

                //Top Level Variant Grid
                string[] varDataKeys = new string[] { "ItemID", "HistoryDate" };
                List<BOMHistoryGridColumn> lstVarCols = new List<BOMHistoryGridColumn>();

                lstVarCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("ItemID", "ItemID", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(8)));
                lstVarCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("HistoryDate", "HistoryDate", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(38)));
                lstVarCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("Cost", "Cost", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(12)));
                lstVarCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("MfgrPartListSale", "MfgrPartListSale", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(8)));
                lstVarCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("MfgrPartWSale", "MfgrPartWSale", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(8)));

                SetTopLevelGrid(grd, "ItemHistory", varDataKeys, lstVarCols, "", "");

                //Item Table
                string[] dataKeys = new string[] { "BOMId", "Item.ItemTypeId", "ParentItemId", "ChildItemId" };
                List<BOMHistoryGridColumn> lstItemCols = new List<BOMHistoryGridColumn>();
                if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("BillOfMaterialListing.aspx"))
                    lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("ChildItemId", "ID", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5)));
                else
                    lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("ChildItemId", "ID", "LinkTemplate", Unit.Percentage(5)));

                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("BOMId", "BOM ID", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5)));

                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("Item.AltNbr", "Alt Nbr", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(6)));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("Item.ItemType", "Item Type", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(7)));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("Item.Description", "Item Name", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(7)));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("Notes", "Notes", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(7)));


                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("ParentStockingUOMQty", "Qty Used in Parent's Stocking UOM", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(6), "{0:F4}"));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("ParentStockingUOMExtCost", "Parent Stocking UOM Ext Cost", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:C4}"));


                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("FirstUOMCost", "First UOM Cost", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:F4}"));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("TotalQty", "First UOM Qty", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:F4}"));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("FirstUOM", "First UOM", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:C4}"));

                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("UsageCost", "Usage UOM Cost", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:C4}"));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("UsageQty", "Usage UOM Qty", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:F4}"));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("UsageScrap", "Usage Scrap", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:F4}"));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("UsageUOM", "Usage UOM", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5)));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("UsageExtCost", "Usage UOM Ext Cost", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:C4}"));


                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("StockingCost", "Stocking UOM Cost", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:C4}"));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("StockingQty", "Stocking UOM Qty", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5), "{0:F4}"));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("StockingUOM", "Stocking UOM", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5)));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("QtyOH", "Qty O/H", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5)));
                //Unit.Pixel(100)

                if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("BillOfMaterialListing.aspx"))
                    lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("RoutingId", "Routing ID", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(4)));
                else
                    lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("RoutingId", "Rout ID", "LinkTemplate", Unit.Percentage(4)));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("PatternNbr", "Pattern Nbr", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(6)));
                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("OperationTemplate", "", "OperationTemplate", Unit.Percentage(3)));

                //if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() != "Asset")
                if (Type != "Asset")
                {
                    lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("Past52Weeks", "Past 52 Wks", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5)));
                    lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("NbrOfCust", "Nbr of Cust", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(4)));
                }


                //if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "FinishedGood")
                if (Type == "FinishedGood")
                    lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("CheckBoxTemplatePrimaryMaterial", "Primary Material", "CheckBoxColumn", Unit.Percentage(6)));


                //if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "FinishedGood")
                if (Type == "FinishedGood")
                    lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("CheckBoxTemplatePrimary", "Primary Packaging", "CheckBoxColumn", Unit.Percentage(6)));

                lstItemCols.Add(new BOMHistoryGridColumn("IsBOMChanged", "", "Bound", Unit.Percentage(5)));

             SetTopLevelGrid(grd, "Item", dataKeys, lstItemCols, "ParentItemId", "ChildItemId");

            }

            phMain.Controls.Add(grd);
            //grd.Rebind();
        }


private RadGrid SetTopLevelGrid(RadGrid grid, string tblName, string[] dataKeys, List<BOMHistoryGridColumn> columns, string selfHierarchyParentId, string selfHierarchyChildId)
        {
            grid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = dataKeys;
            grid.MasterTableView.EnableColumnsViewState = false;

            grid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            //grid.PageSize = 20;
            grid.PageSize = 999;
            grid.AllowPaging = true;
            grid.AllowSorting = true;

            grid.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced;
            grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            grid.ShowStatusBar = false;
            //grid.MasterTableView.PageSize = 20;
            grid.MasterTableView.PageSize = 999;
            grid.MasterTableView.Name = tblName;
            grid.ClientSettings.Selecting.AllowRowSelect = true;

            grid.ClientSettings.Scrolling.AllowScroll = true;
            grid.ClientSettings.Scrolling.UseStaticHeaders = true;
            grid.ClientSettings.Scrolling.SaveScrollPosition = true;
            grid.ClientSettings.Scrolling.ScrollHeight = 500;
            grid.ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnGridCreated = "GridCreated";




            GridColumnGroup colGrop = new GridColumnGroup();
            colGrop.HeaderText = "Child First UOM";
            colGrop.Name = "ChildFirstUOM";
            colGrop.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            colGrop.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "firstUOM";
            grid.MasterTableView.ColumnGroups.Add(colGrop);

            GridColumnGroup colGrop1 = new GridColumnGroup();
            colGrop1.HeaderText = "Child Usage";
            colGrop1.Name = "ChildUsage";
            colGrop1.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            colGrop1.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "specificHeader";
            grid.MasterTableView.ColumnGroups.Add(colGrop1);

            GridColumnGroup colGrop2 = new GridColumnGroup();
            colGrop2.HeaderText = "Child Stocking UOM";
            colGrop2.Name = "ChildStockingUOM";
            colGrop2.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            colGrop2.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "stockingCost";
            grid.MasterTableView.ColumnGroups.Add(colGrop2);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selfHierarchyChildId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selfHierarchyParentId))
            {
                grid.MasterTableView.HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.ServerOnDemand;
                grid.MasterTableView.SelfHierarchySettings.KeyName = selfHierarchyChildId;
                grid.MasterTableView.SelfHierarchySettings.ParentKeyName = selfHierarchyParentId;
                grid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = selfHierarchyParentId + " = 0";
            }

            AddColumnsToGridTableView(grid.MasterTableView, columns);

            return grid;
        }
protected void rgrdMain_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (!IsPostBack)
            //{
            //    GridTableView gtv = (sender as RadGrid).MasterTableView;
            //    if (gtv != null)
            //    {
            //        if (gtv.Items.Count > 0)
            //            gtv.Items[0].Expanded = true;
            //    }
            //}


            HideOperationsColumnForChilds((sender as RadGrid).MasterTableView);
        }

        protected void rgrdMain_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            RadGrid rgrdMain = source as RadGrid;

            //if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ID"]) > 0)
            //{
            //    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "Product")
            //    {
            //        Product objProd = new Product();
            //        objProd.ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ID"]);
            //        rgrdMain.DataSource = objProd.GetProductVariants();
            //    }

            //    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim() == "Variant")
            //    {
            //        Variant objVar = new Variant();
            //        objVar.VariantId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ID"]);
            //        rgrdMain.DataSource = objVar.GetVariantFinishedGoods();
            //    }
            //}
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ItemID"]) >= 0)
            {
                Item objItem = new Item();
                objItem.ItemId = Id;
                rgrdMain.DataSource = objItem.GetItemHistory();
                objItem = null;
            }
            if (rgrdMain.DataSource != null)
                ramMain.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(rgrdMain, rgrdMain, this.Page.FindControl("ralpMain") as RadAjaxLoadingPanel);

        }


protected void rgrdMain_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            //For 100% width
            e.Item.OwnerTableView.Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);

            if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.CommandItem)
            {
                //Image imgAssignNew = e.Item.FindControl("imgAssignNew") as Image;
                //LinkButton lnkbtnAssignNew = e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtnAssignNew") as LinkButton;
                //Image imgCloneBOM = e.Item.FindControl("imgCloneBOM") as Image;
                //LinkButton lnkbtnCloneBOM = e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtnCloneBOM") as LinkButton;

                //imgCloneBOM.Visible = false;
                //lnkbtnCloneBOM.Visible = false;

                //Hide CommandItem for Child Tables
                if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.ParentItem != null)
                    e.Item.Visible = false;

                //switch (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Type"]).Trim())
                switch (Type)
                {
                    case "Product":
                        //imgAssignNew.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return ShowSearch('Assign Product - BOM'," + Convert.ToString(ViewState["ID"]).Trim() + ", 'Product'," + Convert.ToString(0).Trim() + ", 'BOM'," + Convert.ToString(0).Trim() + ");");
                        //lnkbtnAssignNew.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return ShowSearch('Assign Product - BOM'," + Convert.ToString(ViewState["ID"]).Trim() + ", 'Product'," + Convert.ToString(0).Trim() + ", 'BOM'," + Convert.ToString(0).Trim() + ");");
                        break;
                    case "Variant":
                        //imgAssignNew.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return ShowSearch('Assign Variant - BOM'," + Convert.ToString(ViewState["ID"]).Trim() + ", 'Variant'," + Convert.ToString(0).Trim() + ", 'BOM'," + Convert.ToString(0).Trim() + ");");
                        //lnkbtnAssignNew.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return ShowSearch('Assign Variant - BOM'," + Convert.ToString(ViewState["ID"]).Trim() + ", 'Variant'," + Convert.ToString(0).Trim() + ", 'BOM'," + Convert.ToString(0).Trim() + ");");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                RadToolTip rttHistory = e.Item.FindControl("rttHistory") as RadToolTip;
                //ImageButton imgbtnEdit = e.Item.FindControl("imgbtnEdit") as ImageButton;
                ImageButton imgbtnHistory = e.Item.FindControl("imgbtnHistory") as ImageButton;
                //ImageButton imgbtnDelete = e.Item.FindControl("imgbtnDelete") as ImageButton;

                if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name == "Variant")
                {
                    Variant objVar = e.Item.DataItem as Variant;
                    LinkButton lnkbtnVariantNo = e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtnVariantNo") as LinkButton;

                    //imgbtnEdit.Visible = true;
                    lnkbtnVariantNo.Text = objVar.VariantNo;
                    rttHistory.Text = GeneralData.GetHistoryTooltipText(objVar.Deleted, objVar.CreatedOn, objVar.CreatedBy, objVar.LastModifiedOn, objVar.LastModifiedBy);
                    //imgbtnEdit.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return EditBOMVariant(" + objVar.VariantId.ToString() + "); return false;");

                    lnkbtnVariantNo.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "if(window.parent){window.parent.openMasterInNewWindow('var','" + objVar.VariantId.ToString() + "');} return false;");
                    //imgbtnDelete.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?');");

                }

                if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name == "FinishedGood")
                {
                    FinishedGood objFg = e.Item.DataItem as FinishedGood;
                    LinkButton lnkbtnSize = e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtnSize") as LinkButton;
                    LinkButton lnkbtnRoutingMaster = e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtnRoutingMaster") as LinkButton;

                    //imgbtnEdit.Visible = false;
                    lnkbtnSize.Text = objFg.Size;
                    if (lnkbtnRoutingMaster != null)
                    {
                        lnkbtnRoutingMaster.Text = objFg.RoutingMaster.ToString();
                        lnkbtnRoutingMaster.Visible = true;
                        if (objFg.RoutingMaster > 0)
                            lnkbtnRoutingMaster.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "if(window.parent){window.parent.openMasterInNewWindow('rout','" + objFg.RoutingMaster.ToString() + "');} return false;");
                        else
                            lnkbtnRoutingMaster.Visible = false;
                    }

                    rttHistory.Text = GeneralData.GetHistoryTooltipText(objFg.Deleted, objFg.CreatedOn, objFg.CreatedBy, objFg.LastModifiedOn, objFg.LastModifiedBy);

                    lnkbtnSize.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "if(window.parent){window.parent.openMasterInNewWindow('fgood','" + objFg.FinishedGoodId.ToString() + "');} return false;");
                    //imgbtnDelete.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?');");

                }
            }


        }

        protected void rgrdMain_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.ExpandCollapseCommandName)
            {
                if (!e.Item.Expanded)
                {
                    //Only for Item grid in NeadtedTemplet
                    if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name == "Item")
                    {
                        //Rebind Child Item Grid on Expand
                        RadGrid grid = ((GridDataItem)e.Item).ChildItem.FindControl("rgrdItem") as RadGrid;
                        grid.Rebind();
                    }
                }

                RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).ResponseScripts.Add("if(window.parent){if(window.parent.resizeIFrame){window.parent.resizeIFrame();}}");
            }


        }
```

Where I am  wrong in my code please help !!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess there is a server error in the loading of the user control.  Set a breakpoint here and see if userControl is what  you expect.  panel.Controls.Add(userControl);   The tricky thing about AJAX is you can get a server error and there will be no indication in the UI.

Comment: panel.Controls.Add(userControl) don't throw error...without nested the gird perfectly work..but when i bind grid in panel then child grid don't show...

Comment: thank you for reply its work...from sql i not return that filed value.so parent and child relation not match..that's way not display...thank you buddy..